# Какая лучшая практика в QML перетаскивать только часть объекта или изменять внешний вид объекта при перетаскивании?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qml

Вот что я хочу получить. Нажав на некий квадратик (Rectangle) внутри сцены кнопкой мыши я делаю действие "перетаскивание" и надо, чтобы рисовалась ("тянулась") стрелка от этого квадратика до курсора во все время перетаскивания. Я создал класс стрелки, унаследовав от QQuickItem и внутри описал updatePaintNode что-то вроде:

```
QSGNode *Arrow::updatePaintNode(QSGNode *n, QQuickItem::UpdatePaintNodeData *)
{
    QSGGeometryNode *node = static_cast<QSGGeometryNode *>(n);
    if (!node)
        node = new QSGGeometryNode();

    _geometry.setLineWidth(2);
    _geometry.setDrawingMode(GL_LINE_STRIP);

    QSGGeometry::Point2D *v = _geometry.vertexDataAsPoint2D();

    const QRectF rect = boundingRect();

    QPointF itemStartPoint(_startX, _startY);
    //Переводим в глобальную систему координат
    QPointF sceneStartPoint = mapFromItem(nullptr, itemStartPoint);


    v[0].x = sceneStartPoint.x();
    v[0].y = sceneStartPoint.y();

    v[1].x = rect.left();
    v[1].y = rect.top();

    node->setGeometry(&_geometry);
    node->setMaterial(&_material);

    return node;
}
```

потом натравил **drag.target** на объект стрелки внутри сцены. При перетаскивании перетаскивается вся стрелка, а не ее "кончик", единственный способ, который придумал, это делать **update();** внутри **onXChanged** и **onYChanged** стрелки:

```
Arrow {
    id: defaultArrow;
    width: 1;
    height: 1;

    onXChanged: {
        update();
    }

    onYChanged: {
        update();
    }

}
```

Это сработало, но что-то кажется как-то коряво это. Есть ли более кошерный способ? Без постоянного вызова **update();**? Может вообще не на основе drag n drop, так как во всех поставляемых примерах на эту тему речь идет о перетаскивании объектов целиком, а мне нужно чтобы при перетаскивании начало стрелки не двигалось.

В общем случае - как перетаскивать "часть" объекта или изменять его внешний вид во время перетаскивания? Например, может понадобится выделение объектов с помощью "прямоугольной области", как это работает при выделение нескольких файлов, и вот нужно будет двигать только "уголок" этой "прямоугольной области", а она сама должна изменять форму, подствечивая попадающие в нее объекты.

Comment: На мой взгляд, у стрелки должны быть начальные координаты и target node, к которому она привязывается. Стрелка всегда будет рисоваться из начала координат(своих) и оканчиваться где-то в объекте(как Вы зададите ей окончание), при этом её окончание будет зависеть от (x, y) целевого объекта. Т.е. стрелка ничего не знает о drag'n'drop

Comment: @ixSci что значить "привязываться" к объекту? Логически или особый кьюэмеловский термин? Я делал что-то вроде этого - перетаскивал невидимый айтим, а в нем менял конечную точку стрелки в событии на перемещнении, но там по сути тоже самое, нужно вызывать update для стрелки, чтобы был эффект (но только больше лишней мороки с лишним объектом, поэтому перешел на перемещение самой стрелки)

Comment: Ну в QML можно задать свойство типа Item, в которое поместить объект. Во время привязки, стрелка привяжется к (x,y) координатам этого объекта. Или вообще, не морочить голову, а сразу привязываться к этим координатам

Comment: @ixSci Двигаю Item (для видимости сделал Rectangle), внутри которого добавил свою стрелку. Тоже самое - без update() двигает всю стрелку целиком, а не кончик